# Entity Framework 7 in Class Library

Tags: c#, entity-framework, console-application, class-library

Can I use a EF7 Code First in a Class Library to be referenced by a Console Application?

I'm preparing/creating a Database to be used in multiple projects in the future.
Now I need to play around with EF7 but not in ASP. Im ok with Console.

Now in a console application to management the first data.
Then in the Final Release of ASP.NET Core 1.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes.  You just need to add Entity Framework references, typically via NuGet.

Answer (score 1):

**EF/NuGet**

Assuming you are using Visual Studio, you would use the built in NuGet functionality to download and install the package.  Here is a detailed [tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712906).

The easiest thing to do from that link is to open the `Package Manager Console` window and type the following: `Install-Package EntityFramework`.  This will install the latest version which happens to currently be `6.1.3`.

**EF Without NuGet**

If you don't use Visual Studio or you cannot use NuGet for whatever reason, you can manually download the package from the [EF NuGet Site](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/) and rename it from a `.nupkg` extension to a `.zip` extension and extract the DLL from the `lib` folder.

**EF7**

Now your question specifically mentions `EF7` which is can be installed using NuGet with the following command: `Install-Package EntityFramework.Commands -Pre` in the Package Manager Console.

If you don't have NuGet, you can follow the steps above or download the source from [GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/releases/tag/7.0.0-rc1) and build the DLL yourself.  Having said that, it is a RC so use at your own risk.

Comment: [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.Commands/) is the rc1 NuGet package for EF7